# Getting a bool reference from std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, boolean, stdvector

I know it's a bad habit, but I'd like to know some workaround or hack for this problem.
I have a class like this:

```
template <class T>
class A : std::vector<T> {
  T& operator()(int index) { // returns a _reference_ to an object
    return this->operator[](index);
  }
};
```

It's possible to do things like this:

```
A<int> a{1,2,3,4};
a(3) = 10;
```

But it stops working if somebody uses **bool** as a template parameter

```
A<bool> a{true, false, true};
std::cout << a(0) << std::endl; // not possible
if (a(1)) { /* something */ }   // not possible
```

`std::vector<bool>` is a specialized version of vector (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/) which doesn't allow such things.

Is there a way how to get a reference of boolean variable from std::Vector? Or any different solution?

Comment: Does it produce a compilation error?  Or does it compile okay but fail to work somehow?

Comment: You could provide a specialization for `A<bool>` that doesn't use `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way how to get a reference of boolean variable from std::Vector?

No.

> Or any different solution?

Return `typename std::vector<T>::reference` instead of `T&`. For `bool`, it will return the vector's proxy type; for others, it will return a regular reference.

Or specialise `A<bool>` to use something other than `vector<bool>`.

Or use some other type (perhaps `char`, or a simple class wrapping a `bool`) instead of `bool`.

Answer (score 9):

You hit the curse of the fake-container specialization.

That's an acknowledged design-error the standard still propagates, so you need to specialize your template to avoid the standard-specialization.

Use a `std::vector<mybool>` with `struct mybool{bool value;};` or some such in your specialization (and curse the stubborn committee for not deprecating it fast and undoing their error by now).

Alternatively, just return `std::vector<T>::reference` instead of `T&`. (Abstain if possible, don't propagate that wart) (Don't forget proper cursing)